# Is the Input Split size constant or does it depend on Logical record?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Hadoop Definitive Guide says:

```
When you have Minimum split size 1, Maximum split size Long.MAX_VALUE, Block 
size 64MB then the Split size is 64MB.
```

TextInputFormat's logical records are lines. As the each line length is different how can we have split of size exactly 64MB?

Answer (score 3):

HDFS blocks are sequences of bytes. They are not aware of lines or any other structure. 
So you might have a split made of only one block (of course of size 64MB) ending in the middle of a line (i.e. not including the whole last line). When you read it with TextInputFormat, it will take care to read some bytes form the next block too so that you get also the entire last line.

Comment: So can I say Split size is not constant?

Comment: So, why is the split size not constant in the above scenario? Except for the last block, the split should be 64MB. One thing to note is even though record might span across blocks, this is handled by the Hadoop framework and is transparent to the end user.

Comment: the split size, in  this scenario is 64MB + remaining_part_of_last_line => it might be not perfectly constant.

Answer (score 1):

Always follow the 2 rules:

1. Determine if your in the middle of a record
2. can over that record and read the next full record

The first half of the record goes as the last record of previous InputSplit